# Best cross-platform library?

Tags: c#

I need a good cross-platform library to use for C#. I've tried GTK# but it looks horrible in windows. I've tried wx.NET but is a pain to get it to work properly in linux. And the rest appear to only be for C++. Would it be just better to switch over to manage C++, and if so what would be a good library to use for C++? Thanks!

Edit: Windows, & Linux most preferred.

Comment: Suggestion : might be helpful to clarify exactly which platforms your app must run on. best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) (pronounced "cute"). And [this link](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/activeqt-dotnet.html) should get you on your way to use it from C#.

Comment: As an American, I can't bring myself to call it "cute" - it has to be QT for me.

Comment: The link you gave me is a bit confusing on how to start using it with C#. Are there any compiled examples that I can use to learn from? Thanks!

Comment: @JimDaniel - I kept calling it Q.T. myself, until I met someone from Nokia who pronounced it for me :)

Comment: @mail_321 didn't dig too much into it, but the article provides a good start place. Essentially, you can use Interop to access almost anything from within .Net. I assume that you'll be using Mono on platforms other than Windows.

Comment: @Dan not according to Nokia, or Daniel Rocha, who gave the Qt lecture in DevDays SF.

Comment: @Traveling Tech Guy - I have a question which I can't seem to find on their website: Do I need to compile differently for use on Linux/Windows? Do I pass the same exact files across to use in different platforms? Thanks! Your great help so far!

Comment: It doesn't look like you have to do anything special, although in Windows, you could (don't have to, just could) compile Qt to an ActiveX, making the Interop integration almost drag-n-droppy (if that's a word :))

Comment: Just reading up on deploying Qt apps and did the tutorial, I'll have to include all the Qt dlls that are linked, and they are HUGE, the GUI library itself is 134mb.... Is there a better and more compact solution?

Answer (score 0):

Miguel de Icaza's blog had a great discussion regarding how Silverlight has become a great cross platform option for C# dev's.    On mac and PC, you have great implementations from Microsoft which support subsets of XAML.   On Linux, the Novell team has done a great job implementing silverlight on a linux stack.   I think it's great that Microsoft has been openly supporting their efforts as well.  (I believe some moonlight unit tests are provided by the MS Silverlight team.)

It is an option to consider:
http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Nov-23.html